# MSDeploy (run from bat) returns Access is denied

Tags: batch-file, msdeploy

I'm trying to call msdeploy from a .bat file but I get an "Access denied" error. My user account (as far as I can tell) is an admin user. Here's the line of code:

```
msdeploy.exe -verb:sync -enableRule:Donotdeleterule -source:package="C:\App\App.zip" -dest:auto -setParam:name="IIS Web Application Name",value="App"
```

What are all the settings I should confirm that should have admin privileges?

Comment: Right click and run the batch file with elevated permissions.  See if the behaviour changes.

Comment: Try to **Disable UAC**, restart and then try again.

Comment: @AbdelhafidMadoui: Disabling UAC is always the wrong solution to fixing a problem.

Comment: @foxidrive I'm running it from the command line which I "ran as administrator".

Comment: It's not clear if you ran from an elevated cmd prompt or you think that because you are admin that you have full permissions.  Many people incorrectly think the latter.

Comment: Does right-clicking on "Command Prompt" and choosing "run as administrator" mean that it will execute the .bat with elevated privileges? This is what I did... Am I still missing something?

Answer (score 0):

Test this to see if anything changes.  It just has an escaped comma.

A

```
msdeploy.exe -verb:sync -enableRule:Donotdeleterule -source:package="C:\App\App.zip" -dest:auto -setParam:name="IIS Web Application Name"^,value="App"
```

You may like to try the following two variations too.

B

```
msdeploy.exe -verb:sync -source:package="C:\App\App.zip" -dest:auto -setParam:name="IIS Web Application Name",value="App" -enableRule:Donotdeleterule
```

C

```
msdeploy.exe -verb:sync -source:package="C:\App\App.zip" -dest:auto -setParam:name="IIS Web Application Name"^,value="App" -enableRule:Donotdeleterule
```

Comment: Sincere thanks for the suggestions but those didn't seem to work. My .bat file seems to work just fine on another server. The only thing different I see about this server is that I once installed the Application Request Routing plugin for IIS. But I don't see how that would affect this... I could try removing it as I'm not using it at all.

Comment: It looks like even though the containing folder was in the Path Environment variable, it still couldn't find msdeploy. I called msdeploy by including the full path and it works.